# Is there a reasoned derivation of the coherence conditions for symmetric rig categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, algorithms, coherence

I know *what* the coherence conditions are, I can look them up in

- M. Laplaza, Coherence for distributivity, Lecture Notes in Mathematics 281, Springer Verlag, Berlin, 1972, pp. 29-72.

In theory, apparently I can find these also in

- G. Kelly, Coherence theorems for lax algebras and distributive laws, Lecture Notes in Mathematics 420, Springer Verlag, Berlin, 1974, pp. 281-375.

but I tried to find them there, and failed.  Note that I really mean [rig category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rig+category) here, as I definitely want non-strictness, so [bipermutative categories](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bipermutative+category) will not do.  (The main examples I am trying to understand are the rig category of permutations with $\oplus$ as disjoint union and $\otimes$ as tensor product, and the probably-rig-category of Types).

I am already aware of the work by Beke -- [Categorification, term rewriting and the Knuth-Bendix procedure](http://faculty.uml.edu/tbeke/knuth.pdf), which explicitly excludes this case, as the underlying term rewrite system is not confluent.

There might be something in the work of JA Cohen, in particular in [Coherence without unique normal forms](http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.4334) or his thesis [Coherence for rewriting 2-theories](http://arxiv.org/abs/0904.0125), but I have having a hard time extracting an explicit algorithm from these.  In the same way, there might be something in the works Guirand and Malbos, Lafont or Mimram (see the links at the end of the nLab page on [rewriting](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/rewriting), but I am unable to extract an explicit algorithm from these).

I am, above all, looking for a *reasoned* derivation of the coherence conditions, rather than something ad hoc that just happens to work.  A general rewriting theory would be the kind of answer I would prefer; but any kind of **explicit algorithm** would be satisfying as well.

Comment: If the "addition" monoidal structure is the coproduct then you don't need to worry about coherence conditions; you just need to say that tensoring with a fixed object preserves coproducts (unlike preserving a general symmetric monoidal structure, this is a property, not a structure). See http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/distributive+monoidal+category.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, Thanks for the reference to distributive monoidal categories.  While some of the situations we are studying fall into that case, not all of them do.  We are explicitly interested in cases where the "addition" monoidal structure does NOT come from an underlying coproduct (such as for B = (finite sets + bijections)).